# Unable to import 'gi' after using MSYS2 to install PyGObject

Tags: python, gstreamer, pygobject

I am currently trying to run the following code:

```
import cv2
import gi
import numpy as np

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst
```

The error i am getting is 'Unable to import 'gi''

I have followed the instructions here: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

And used this command in the MSYS2 MinGW 64x terminal:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gstreamer mingw-w64-x86_64-gst-devtools mingw-w64-x86_64-gst-plugins-{base,good,bad,ugly} mingw-w64-x86_64-python3 mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-gobject
```

I'm using python 3.10 in vscode

Please let me know if you need any more information to help